# npm WARN deprecated when running 'vue init webpack my-project'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack

**My Goal**:wanna initialize Vue.js project by running commands `vue init webpack myproject`

**Expected Result**: install all the dependencies with no fatal error, AND would be able to start running the project by `npm dev run`,and run project on http://localhost:8080

**ACTUAL Result**:

```
# Installing project dependencies ...
# ========================

npm WARN deprecated extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2: Deprecated. Please use https://gi
thub.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browsersli
st >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated bfj-node4@5.3.1: Switch to the `bfj` package for fixes and new featu
res!
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommend
ed for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actua
l version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslis
t >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is
 its successor.
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...,"dist":{"shasum":"1e'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-12T06_01_01_
430Z-debug.log


Running eslint --fix to comply with chosen preset rules...
# ========================


> travel@1.0.0 lint F:\SourceCode\Travel-master\Travel
> eslint --ext .js,.vue src "--fix"


Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 6.8.0.

ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-vue".

(The package "eslint-plugin-vue" was not found when loaded as a Node module from the dir
ectory "F:\SourceCode\Travel-master\Travel".)

It's likely that the plugin isn't installed correctly. Try reinstalling by running the f
ollowing:

    npm install eslint-plugin-vue@latest --save-dev

The plugin "eslint-plugin-vue" was referenced from the config file in ".eslintrc.js".

If you still can't figure out the problem, please stop by https://gitter.im/eslint/eslin
t to chat with the team.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! travel@1.0.0 lint: `eslint --ext .js,.vue src "--fix"`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the travel@1.0.0 lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging out
put above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-12T06_01_04_
492Z-debug.log

# Project initialization finished!
# ========================

To get started:

  cd Travel
  npm run dev

Documentation can be found at https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack
```

**What I've tried**

run the commands like above mentioned `npm install eslint-plugin-vue@latest --save-dev`,then comes another issue like below:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for eslint-plugin-vue@lastest.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-12T06_09_11_
766Z-debug.log
```

even I tried the `npm install webpack -dev-server -g`,then comes another issue like below:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\webpack -> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\webpack\bin\webp
ack.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\webpack\no
de_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11:
wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ webpack@4.41.6
added 322 packages from 197 contributors in 255.517s
```

Comment: Your error shows that your command used `lastest` instead of `latest`. But in any case, the project you're attempting to create is long obsolete by Vue CLI. You could create an up to date project with `vue create myproject`. Note it abstracts the webpack config (shields you from it), but you could configure it in `vue.config.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem when coding my app (MEVN) and using the command `vue init webpack client`.

So I did a bit of research notably on npm to see what was wrong and found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli so apparently you can't use this command anymore.

So if you wish to use the vue cli you need to install it trough `npm install -g @vue/cli` and then run `vue create <dir name>`

For further information you can look into the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli with the documentation on the vuejs website: https://cli.vuejs.org/

Hope this helps and have fun coding